# Variable says it's not defined, but it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, defined

**error info:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/python/footballcomplex.py", line 85, in <module>
    if input2 == 'a':
NameError: name 'input2' is not defined
```

**this is line 83-85:**

```
input2 = input("Would you like to long pass to 3(a) or through ball to 2(b)")

if input2 == 'a':
```

If you want to read the whole thing right now :

`link to code`https://pastebin.com/bhYMKa8M

The problem is for when I put b or c for the first a,b and c question.But A works perfectly fine.

*Please help I literally have no idea.
Python ver 3.7*

Comment: The call to `input` is part of the `if`-block in the code before. The indentation is nearly invisible because you indent with only one space. For heavens sake, please respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and use four spaces to indent each level.

Comment: "... but it is." No, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the indentation before `line83`

Answer (score 1):

Line 83,

```
input2 = input("Would you like to long pass to 3(a) or through ball to 2(b)")
```

is in the if statement before it.

```
if input1 == 'a':
```

Right now it is only asking for input when input1=='a', but if you take that indentation out it will ask for input regardless of input1

Comment: you have passed input2 in a if condition of input1 , remove the extra space before the statement,  input2 = input("Would you like to long pass to 3(a) or through ball to 2(b)")